# Rails unable to get before_destroy to call when deleting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been at this for a while and need a smarter person's opinion.  I'm trying to check the passcode I have in my database matches the passcode the user enters in order to delete a record.  I believe that I should be doing this in the model, and I am refactoring to use the before_destroy method.  However I can't even get the before_destroy method to execute when I click on the delete button I made.  The controller does execute the destroy method though.

View

```
<%= button_to('Destroy', @dish, method: "delete") %>
```

Model - the puts passcode_check? is never called from what I see

```
class Dish < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_destroy :passcode_check?
   validates :username, presence: true
   validates :passcode, presence: true
   validates :guests, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

  private

  def passcode_check?
    puts "passcode_check?"
     if @dish.passcode != params[:pass]
       @dish.errors.add( :base, 'Unable to delete record; Reason: Passcodes did not match.')
       return false
     else
       @dish.errors.add( :base, 'test.')
       return false
     end
   end 
end
```

Controller - this method is influx as I want to validate in the model

```
  def destroy
    if @dish.passcode == params[:pass]
      @dish.destroy unless @dish.errors
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to dishes_url, notice: 'Record delete.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @dish, action: 'show', notice: 'Unable to delete record; Reason: Passcodes did not match.' }
        format.json { render json: @dish.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity  }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Are there `@dish.errors`?

Comment: Does the record actually get destroyed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller you're using `@dish.errors` which will always return an `ActiveModel::Errors` object and therefore be truthy. So the `unless @dish.errors` statement modifier never lets `@dish.destroy` run and consequently neither will your callback. Change it to:

```
@dish.destroy if @dish.errors.empty?
```

And that should be it. Although it doesn't make much sense to check for errors yet since no validations have even run. Just call `@dish.destroy` and let your before_destroy callback halt the deletion by returning false and, conversely, let the deletion happen by returning true.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I see that I was blocking my own call now.